# NestJS SSE - What's the diffference between using interval and fromEvent from client perspective?

Tags: rxjs, nestjs, server-sent-events

Here are 2 SSE methods in NestJS :
The first one is using `interval` method to return an observable and the second one returns an observable of events (EventEmitter).

In a scenario where multiple clients are connected to the same SSE endpoint the behavior is different.
In the `interval` method not all clients the same message , but in `fromEvent` observable they all get the same message when an event is fired.

What's the difference between those methods if they all return an Observable ?

```js
    @Sse('sse')
    sse(): Observable<MessageEvent> {
        return interval(5000)
            .pipe(map((_) => ({ data: { hello: `world - ${this.c++}` }} as MessageEvent)),
        );
    }

    @Sse('approvals')
    public getApprovals(@Res() response: Response): Observable<MessageEvent> {
         return fromEvent(this.eventEmitter, NEW_APPROVAL_EVENT_NAME)
            .pipe(map((data: ApprovalDTO) => {
                this.logger.log(`Event Notification - name:${NEW_APPROVAL_EVENT_NAME}, data:${JSON.stringify(data)}`)
                return new MessageEvent<ApprovalDTO>('new-approval', { data: data });
            }),
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the `interval` will create a new interval observable, so each client that calls `SSE /sse` will create a new observable that emits the `hello: world - ${ this.c++ }` every five seconds, meaning that `this.c` can, and will, be incremented more than once every 5 seconds for the number of clients that are attached. The `fromEvent()` *also* creates a new observable, but this observable **only** fires when the `NEW_APPROVAL_EVENT_NAME` event is emitted, so all the clients see that happen at the same time. There's still X observables for X clients, but they all trigger at the same time with the same data. If you were to add a similar `this.d++` to he returned object, you would see that they all have a different value even on the `SSE /approvals` route.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, it's a shared variable (`this.c`) that makes it not to seem consistent. right ?

Comment: Yeah, the server keeps track of the state, and the class is what the state belongs to. It doesn't belong to the observable